# batch that change particular string on a .txt file

Tags: batch, string

I have a example.txt witch contanins:

```
[DDRAWSINK]
PlaybackDisp=0
Fullscreen=0
CurUsage=2
PlaybackRes=0
ForceRender=0
DV Output On=0
DV Preview VGA=0
DV Port=0
```

single lines can have only 1 alphanumerical value, for example

CurUsage can have only 2, or 3 or 0 or 9. Never 10 or -1 or 200

and this is the same for other elements (PlaybackDisp, ForceRender, DV Output On etc..)

they can only have a value between 0 and 9.

I would like change single value by a batch file, for example I need to assign to Fullscreen the "1" value instead of 0.

The batch have to recognize "Fullscreen" and change 0 ---> to 1

Is it possible? thanks

Comment: Yes. What have you tried so far? [SU] isn't a script writing service.Hint: editing with batch involvers rewriting the file. Parse the file with a `for /f`, split the lines at the equal sign and check for `Fullscreen`

Comment: eh ok but I'm poor and disperate with my pc :( I need help as a cat

Comment: Windows does not have a programmable text editor per se, However, you can add one, following the instructions at https://medium.com/powershell-explained/text-editor-inside-powershell-22d2f5e748b8, IF you have Windows with Powershell. Please click [edit] and amend your question to show if you have Windows 7, 8, 8.1, or 10, and Home, Pro, Education, or Enterprise. With that information, we can help.

Answer (score 0):

There was a very similar question [here](https://superuser.com/a/1386994/381958), and the answer can be munged slightly to get the effect you're after:

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

FOR /F "tokens=1,* delims==" %%i IN (example.txt) DO (
    SET sdone=0
    SET "sname=%%i"
    SET "svalue=%%j"
    ECHO.Name:  !sname!
    ECHO.Value: !svalue!

    :: write out headers
    IF "!sdone!"=="0" IF "!sname:~0,1!"=="[" SET sdone=1&&ECHO.Type:  Header&&ECHO.!sname!>>new.ini

    :: write out the new value if it's "Fullscreen"
    IF "!sdone!"=="0" IF "!sname!"=="Fullscreen" IF "!svalue!"=="0" SET sdone=1&&ECHO.Type:  Rewrite&&ECHO.!sname!=1>>new.ini

    :: write out anything else
    IF "!sdone!"=="0" SET sdone=1&&ECHO.Type:  Content&&ECHO.!sname!=!svalue!>>new.ini

    :: a little padding to read the debug info
    ECHO.
)
```

It reads through the input file (example.txt) then parses the content for headers (indicated by "[") and writes those as-is. Flags that don't match "Fullscreen" will be written out as-is in name=value pairs. If the name of a line is Fullscreen the value will be changed to 1. Empty lines will be skipped.

It writes all changes to a new file, "new.txt", which then needs to be copied back over example.txt (as a safety precaution, this is not included in the code above).

Comment: @CamilloGatto Show thanks by accepting the answer if it solved your problem.